# XSL - Adding Values of nodes based on condition

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

So basically I need a function that loops through XML nodes and IF a condition is true, it adds that value to a variable. I am aggregating social posts and need to count how many of each social post is in the feed. Here is my XML:

```
 <feed>
   <channel>
     <sources>
       <source>
           <name>Facebook</name>
           <count>3</count>
       </source>
       <source>
           <name>Twitter</name>
           <count>2</count>
       </source>
       <source>
           <name>Twitter</name>
           <count>8</count>
        </source>
     </sources>
   </channel>
  </feed>
```

The catch is the same source can appear multiple times, and I need to add those together. So I would need a twitter count of 10 for the above XML. Here is where I am at so far:

```
<xsl:variable name="num_tw">
<xsl:for-each select="feed/channel/sources/source">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="name, 'twitter')">
      <xsl:value-of select="count"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise></xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="num_fb">
<xsl:for-each select="feed/channel/sources/source">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="name, 'facebook')">
      <xsl:value-of select="count"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise></xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

This doesn't work because if there is two twitter feeds it puts the numbers side by side and outputs "28" instead of "10". Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to iterate over the nodes with **xsl:for-each** here. Instead you can just make use of the **sum** operator. For example, your **num_tw** variable can just be re-written like so

```
<xsl:variable name="num_tw" select="sum(feed/channel/sources/source[name='Twitter']/count)"/>
```

However, do you really want to hard-code your feed names here? This is really a 'grouping' issue, and in XSLT 1.0 you use a technique called Muencian Grouping to solve it. In your case, you want to group **source** elements by their **name** element, and so you define a key like so:

```
<xsl:key name="source" match="source" use="name" />
```

Then, you look at all the **source** elements, and pick the one that is first in the group for their given **name** element:

```
<xsl:apply-templates 
   select="feed/channel/sources/source[generate-id() = generate-id(key('source', name)[1])]" />
```

Then, within the template that matches this, you can sum up the counts like so:

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(key('source', name)/count)" />
```

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:key name="source" match="source" use="name" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="feed/channel/sources/source[generate-id() = generate-id(key('source', name)[1])]" />

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="source">
        <source>
            <xsl:copy-of select="name" />
            <count><xsl:value-of select="sum(key('source', name)/count)" /></count>
        </source>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your XML, the following is output:

```
<source>
   <name>Facebook</name>
   <count>3</count>
</source>
<source>
   <name>Twitter</name>
   <count>10</count>
</source>
```

Note that if you did really want to find out the count of a specific feed, like 'Facebook' it would still be preferably to use the key here. For example:

```
<xsl:variable name="num_fb" select="sum(key('source', 'Facebook')/count)"/>
```

Comment: Using SUM() worked great! Thanks a bunch that was exactly what I needed. They Muencian Grouping method actually does seem ideal, I just have to figure out how to implement it using your sample code. I would have to use "call-template" not "apply-templates" because there are a bunch of templates in my XSL doc and I only need it to affect one. I should be able to figure it out, your comment was VERY insightful. So to be clear though, I am creating ab XML nodeset and I would then need to loop through those to get values right?

Comment: As XSLT is a functional language, you should generally try and avoid thinking of more procedural concepts such as 'looping'. Here you are selecting the nodes you want to work on, and in this case, summing a value.